# Is Demographic data from GA / GA4 available in BigQuery?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4, demographics

After linking GA or GA4 with BigQuery, do we get Demographics data (Gender, Age, Interests) in BQ?

If we do - does it happen on the user_id level? ( So info for one specifiic user is available)?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 2):

No, this is unavailable information that Google obtains from its other aggregate tables.

Answer (score 0):

Google does not share this info at the user level.  This is their proprietary information that they gather from your searches and browsing activity and they use it to serve/sell ads, return "relevant" search results, etc.